# Appium(Android Mobile) : Click button using X Y coordinate(if can't find ID or Xpath)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, android, android-automation

Appium(Android Mobile) :  Click button using  X Y coordinate(if can't find ID or Xpath)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably find a element you can find and use an offset from that location. See this to get a Point from element: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/attributes/location/

To click on some coordinates:

```
TouchAction touchAction=new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction.tap(xPoint, yPoint).perform();
```

Code from: https://discuss.appium.io/t/tapping-on-the-screen-by-using-coordinates/5529/8

Comment: Thanks for your comment small correction to your code this is working fine.                                   
       TouchAction touchAction=new TouchAction(driver);
        touchAction.tap(PointOption.point(120, 1456)).perform();

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `console.log(driver.getPageSource())` to target element type